# How to plot in Matlab a Matrix setting 2 axes variables?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, 2d, graphics2d

How to plot a tuple with consistence in two axes. What's option in **2-D** or **3-D** plotting system usable for this case in Matlab.

Format is `[axe_X value axe_Y]`

*axe_X* and *axe_Y* is in `[0.99 0.5 0 -0.5 -0.8 -0.99]`
Value represents instant time that a value have a factor *x* and *y* in *serie*.
Tuple is defined in next line.

```
tuple = [0.99 -0.99 0.44; 0.5 -0.99 0.01; 0 -0.99 0.17; -0.5 -0.99 0.89; -0.8 -0.99 2.1; -0.99 -0.99 1.14; 0.99 -0.5 0.76; 0.5 -0.5 0.17; 0 -0.5 0.03; -0.5 -0.5 0.53; -0.8 -0.5 1.22;-0.5 -0.99 1.18; 0.99 0 0.14; 0.5 0 0.12; 0 0 0.16; -0.5 0 0.17; -0.8 0 1.18; -0.99 0 1.19; 0.99 0.5 0.17; 0.5 0.5 0.10; 0 0.5 0.23; -0.5 0.5 0.12; -0.8 0.5 1.19; -0.99 0.5 1.41;0.99 0.99 0.23; 0.5 0.99 0.09; 0 0.99 0.04; -0.5 0.99 0.19; -0.8 0.99 1.67; -0.99 0.99 1.6;]
```

Comment: How about `plot3(tuple(:,1), tuple(:,3), tuple(:,2))`?

Comment: There's also `surf`, but you'll have to reshape your data.

Comment: @Cris Luengo surf looks a good option, but I'm do not know reshape in Matlab, thanks.

Comment: @kedarps fine looks great solution in 3 axes but I want also show in 2-dimensions